# Expected value of a Poisson process problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, poisson-distribution

The problem is as follows:

> A pizza parlor serves n different types of pizza, and is visited by
> a number $K$ of customers in a given period of time, where $K$ is a Poisson random
> variable with mean $\lambda$. Each customer orders a single pizza, with all types of pizza
> being equally likely, independent of the number of other customers and the types of
> pizza they order. Find the expected number of different types of pizzas ordered.

Here is how I did it:

> Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of different types of pizzas ordered.
>
> Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for when the $i^{th}$ pizza is ordered at least once.
>
> Thus we have:
> $$X = X_1 + ... + X_n$$
> And:
> $$E[X] = nE[X_i]$$
>
> $E[X_i]$ is simply the probability that at least one person orders the $i^{th}$ pizza which is also $1-P(no\:one\:orders)$. The probability that a customer arrives and orders the $i^{th}$ pizza at any infinitesimal period $\delta$ is $\lambda\delta\frac{1}{n}$, thus, we can think of the arrival and ordering process as a Poisson random variable with parameter $\frac{\lambda}{n}$.
>
> Thus, the probability there are no orders in some given time interval $t$ is:
> $$P_P(0,t) = e^{\frac{\lambda}{n}t}$$
>
> Here, $P_P$ is the probability distribution for the number of arrivals $k$ in some interval $\tau$:
> $$P_P(k, \tau) = \frac{(\lambda\tau)^ke^{-\lambda\tau}}{k!}$$
>
> Finally, we have
> $$E[X] = n(1-e^{\frac{\lambda}{n}t})$$

However, the solution seems to not use any time interval, instead the answer is:

> $$E[X] = n(1-e^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})$$

Does anyone know why this is the case? Don't we have to specify a time interval for such a problem? The solution seems to directly use the Poisson distribution which does not depend on an interval. If so, what is $n$ and $p$ here?

Comment: Here $t=1$.  Not necessarily $1$ minute or $1$ year but $1$ "given period of time" and the parameter is $\lambda$ per "given period of time"

Comment: "Number of pizza types ordered" refers to orders in the "given period of time" specified earlier in the problem statement, i.e. they intend for you to use $t=1$. The problem doesn't actually describe a Poisson process; you can replace the first sentence with "$K \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$." (Although you can interpret it as a Poisson process if you like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly you're assuming $t=1$ unit of time, so that the number of customers arriving is actually Poisson $\lambda$.

Here's another approach that might be a bit clearer. Suppose $K=k$. Then easily
$$\mathbb E[X_i\mid K=k]=1-\mathbb P(\text{no one gets }i)=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k.$$
Hence $\mathbb E[X\mid K=k]=n\left(1-(1-1/n)^k\right)$. So by the law of total expectation,
$$\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid K]]=\mathbb E\left[n\left(1-(1-1/n)^K\right)\right]=n\left(1-\mathbb E\left[(1-1/n)^K\right]\right).$$
Now use PGF of the Poisson distribution $\mathbb E\left[t^K\right]=e^{\lambda(t-1)}$ to get the result $$\mathbb E[X]=n\left(1-e^{-\lambda/n}\right).$$
It looks like you're missing a minus sign in the exponent -- the expression that you've written could be negative!